# How to call to "Go to Line" via "com.intellij.openapi"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm looking for a method in "com.intellij.openapi" that get filename, line and column and call to "Go to Line".

This method will navigate to the location ("Not will open the window Go to Line").

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new OpenFileDescriptor(project, file, line, column).navigate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! 
This actually do the jump operation in addition to the move position.

Answer (score 0):

```
getEditor().getCaretModel().moveToLogicalPosition(new LogicalPosition(line, column));
```